# Wordpress subfolder giving 404 error with zend application

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, zend-framework

I am running my zend (1.2) application in my document root. 
folder structure is

```
- application
 - templates
 - www ---> index.php
```

I am creating a folder with these folder names as blog for blog posts.

When I try to run my site with URL: www.site.com/blog is giving me 404 error.

Any help?

.htaccess file (zend).

```
Order deny,allow 
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^blog/ 

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>  
php_value memory_limit 7168M
php_value post_max_size 6144M
php_value upload_max_filesize 5120M
```

Answer (score 0):

Ohh! I just put my wordpress folder inside www and its worked.